# How to make md5 bash command in OSX to read bytes

Tags: macos, bash, md5

I am trying to generate an MD5 out of a string that is a hex byte array (like '2b5ed7db5cf98eda41d10585'). With a normal string I can run `md5 -qs the_text`, but I have no idea on how to make the md5 command to read my byte array instead of reading it as plain text. I want to be able to run the command in a way that

```
echo a | md5  ==  echo 0x63 | md5
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you meant to compare 0x63 to character 'c' and not 'a' since that is the ascii encoding for hex value 63 [confirmed here](http://www.asciitable.com/). You should try backslash notation in bash:

```
# first with plain text
$ echo -e c | md5
2cd6ee2c70b0bde53fbe6cac3c8b8bb1

# with single quotes
$ echo -e '\x63' | md5
2cd6ee2c70b0bde53fbe6cac3c8b8bb1

# or escaping the backslash
$ echo -e \\x63 | md5
2cd6ee2c70b0bde53fbe6cac3c8b8bb1
```

### EDIT

If you're using zsh then you don't need the `-e` flag. If you have to use the Bourne shell 'sh' then you should use `printf`. The caveat is that you have to append a newline `\n` in order to get the same hash as `echo` (since it adds it by default):

```
# using bash
$ printf 'c' | md5
4a8a08f09d37b73795649038408b5f33

$ printf 'c\n' | md5
2cd6ee2c70b0bde53fbe6cac3c8b8bb1

$ printf '\x63\n' | md5
2cd6ee2c70b0bde53fbe6cac3c8b8bb1

$ printf \\x63\\n | md5
2cd6ee2c70b0bde53fbe6cac3c8b8bb1

# using sh
sh-3.2$ printf '\x63\n' | md5
2cd6ee2c70b0bde53fbe6cac3c8b8bb1

sh-3.2$ printf \\x63\\n | md5
2cd6ee2c70b0bde53fbe6cac3c8b8bb1
```

As mentioned in the comments by @Ken, you can also use `$'\x63'` in (ba)sh:

```
sh-3.2$ echo $'\x63' | md5
2cd6ee2c70b0bde53fbe6cac3c8b8bb1
```

Comment: You are right about the 0x63 being the c char, my mistake. I tried your suggestion and doesn't work for me. For the first command I got the same hash, but for the other 2 I got I different one (a13ea8d712b7d2ae9f9327c4ac37b0b7). I tried it in a linux machine as well and also got different hashes :S

Comment: If you had tried simply `echo '\x63'` or `echo \\x63`, you'd see that neither outputs `c`. They are by no means the same as `echo c`. `echo $'\x63'` does work, though.

Comment: @KenThomases I was using zsh in OSX, I forgot to check a more standard shell - thank you for the correction!